# Как забрать данные в определённой строке из таблицы при условии что есть номер?

Tags: java, selenium, selenide

Есть таблица в которой есть номер лота и цена.
**Условие**: нужно собрать цену из той строки таблицы где есть номер ЕИС.
Ход мыслей такой:
- На странице нахожу все элементы по тегу tr.
- Элементы перечисляю и если есть в строке Номер ЕИС, то забираю цену.

Подскажите как реализовать это в selenide или selenium? Спасибо

```
 ElementsCollection trElements = $$(tagName("tr"));
    for (SelenideElement trElement : trElements) {
        if (trElement имеет НОМЕР ЕИС) 
        {
            //забрать из элемента(строки) цену.
        }
    }


<table class="result-table">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="column-main">
                <h6>
                    Номер ЕИС
                </h6>
                <p>
                    <a class="eis_number" target="target_number">31908504358</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="price">
            <p>
                <strong>
                    4 457 757,98
                </strong>
                <span>
                    руб.
                </span>
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй так через Selenium `WebElement`

```
        List <WebElement> table = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='result-table']/tbody/tr"));

        for(int i = 0; i < table.size(); i++){
            String eisNum = table.get(i).findElement(By.xpath("./td[1]/div/h6")).getText();

            if(eisNum.contains("Номер ЕИС")){
                String price = table.get(i).findElement(By.xpath("./td[2]/p/strong")).getText();
                System.out.println("Price: " + price);
            }
        }
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ ! Проблема в том , если элемент не найден в списке, то программа прекращает выполнение , не знаешь как это поправить ?

Comment: @Geferson какой элемент именно? Если его не существует в списке, то смысл его искать?)

Comment: table.get(i) - мы по порядку перечисляем элементы, в первом элементе коллекции нет пути By.xpath("./td[1]/div/h6" и программа выбрасывает исключение. А вот во втором table.get(2)  , есть такой путь и имя там найдёт. Теперь я правильно выразился. Если указанный путь в первом элементе коллекции не находит то что тогда ? )

Comment: Если тэги разные, то попробуй использовать что-то общее для всех. Например если нет 'By.xpath("./td[1]/div/h6")', но есть 'By.xpath("./td[1]/div")', то попробуй такой способ. И если есть возможность, покажи весь HTML код таблицы

Comment: Да ты прав. У таблице в первом элементе нет пути td/div. и я задал индекс со второго элемента for (int a = 1; a < trElements.size(); a++) .

Answer (score 0):

Т.к. в первом элементе нет пути td/div, настроил счётчик со второго.

```
      SelenideElement table = $(byId("Result"));
    ElementsCollection trElements = table.$$(byXpath("id('Result')/table/tbody/tr"));
    for (int a = 1; a < trElements.size(); a++) {
        String eisNum = trElements.get(a).$(byXpath("td/div/h6")).getText();
        if (eisNum.contains("Номер ЕИС")) {
            String price = trElements.get(a).$(byXpath("td/p/strong")).getText();
            System.out.println("Price: " + price);
        }
    }
    }
```